# Iteration issue with dynamic tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, tibble

I am using a tibble: 20 x 1 for iteration extracted from my df.
The problem occurs when I use tibble data as a filter.

```
# Selecting unique list of 20 numeric variables from my data
    Lotes <- unique(dados[,1]) 

# Find its length as Integer for iteration
    LotesMatrix <- length(as.matrix(Lotes)) ##20L
    
# iteration with my df named 'dados'
    for (i in 1:LotesMatrix) {
      Lote <- Lotes[i,1]
      dados1 <- dados[dados$Lote == Lote,]
      print(header(dados1))
    }
```

First iteration occurs fine, but second onwards returns my headers:

```
# ... with 30,048 more rows, and 10 more variables: `TRY-5` <dbl>, `TRY-6` <dbl>, `TRY-7` <dbl>,
#   `TRY-8` <dbl>, `TRY-9` <dbl>, `Total (1-9)` <dbl>, Adicionais <dbl>, Equivalente <dbl>,
#   Total <dbl>, Data <dttm>
# A tibble: 0 x 22
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - the best way to get help here is to post example data, and expected output, along with an explanation of your problem. The description you've given is a little hard to follow without a concrete example. When possible, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to set the dynamic variable searched into string. i.e.

```
Lote <- as.integer(Lotes[i,1])
```